# Amazon MQ cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, amazon-mq

I have Amazon MQ in AWS account A. I want to set this Amazon MQ as a trigger for a lambda function in account B. Lambda does not currently support cross-account triggering for Amazon MQ. How can i do this?

Configure Amazon MQ as trigger for lambda function

Answer (score 0):

When there is no direct support, one needs to build a solution using components that are at their disposal.

Since the end goal is to trigger a lambda function, one option that I can think of is copying the messages from Amazon MQ message broker to AWS SQS as an SQS Queue can be used to [trigger a lambda function in another account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-cross-account-example.html) (assuming that the security policies allow).

For the purpose of copying, there has to be something consuming the MQ broker - another lambda perhaps!